# NodeJS express auto created app binding to server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I created an express app in NodeJS using `express --view=pug expressapp`. It created an app.js file

## app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
...

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

//socket setup
var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(app);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('made socket connection')
})

module.exports = app;
```

at the end I try to bind `socket.io` to app but it expects to bind to server like so

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    
});

//socket setup
var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);
```

I also use `nodemon` so I run the app using `nodemon expressapp` and it runs on port 3000. However I can't find where the auto generated express files have setup the server. Because If i try like this

```
//socket setup
var socket = require('socket.io');

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
        
});

var io = socket(server);
```

I get an error that port 3000 is already in use (by itself) I changed it to `4000` and it works.
Not ideal, if you know how to connect with port `3000` will appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall find it under the directory `bin/www`